# Rails4: Will_paginate gem issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to implement the Will_paginate gem into my rails app, getting error
undefined method `paginate' for #. 
Using gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'

have added the gem to my gemfile and search controller.rb file

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def Home
    access_token = ENV["ACCESS_TOKEN"]
    client = Instagram.client(access_token: access_token)
    default_search = client.tag_search('pizza')

    if params[:q]
      search_query = client.tag_search(params[:q])
      @tag = search_query.present? ? search_query : default_search
    else
      @tag = default_search
    end

    @tag = @tag.first.name
    @results = client.tag_recent_media(@tag)**.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)**
  end

  def about
  end
 end
```

and added to the home page so it displays the page numbers

```
<form action="?" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Instagram photos..." autofocus/>
        </form>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Welcome //
                    <small>It's Nice to Meet You!</small>
                </h1>
     </div>

        <div class="row">
        <% @results.each do |instagram| %>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <%= image_tag instagram.images.low_resolution.url %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <%= will_paginate @results %>
        <br/>
```

Comment: What is `tag_recent_media`

Comment: it returns images via the instagaram api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`will_paginate` only knows how to paginate ActiveRecord queries (and optionally arrays) out of the box.

It doesn't know how to paginate arbitrary apis though. You can use `WillPaginate::Collection` to wrap any data, however it doesn't look like the Instagram api fits very well with this: will paginate assumes that you can skip to an arbitrary offset which you can't with the api. The Instagram api doesn't let you do this - you have to specify the max id and you dont know what that will be other than for the next page of results.

In short it doesn't really look like you can sensibly use `will_paginate` with the Instagram api